# Force Closed with Null Pointer Exception in Android

Tags: java, android

I have this below code which I am trying to test out on the Emulator firstly just to make sure, it is working fine, then I can start testing it on real device.

Below code creates a `Google Map` on the top half of the Android screen and in the Bottom Half the `TextView`. As far as I know whenever you start your application having Google Map, you need to pass the latitude and longitude co-ordinates from the DDMS perspective.

But in my case, I am not passing any location co-ordinates and this below program is throwing `NULL POINTER EXCEPTION` at this line-

```
mScreenPoints = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, mScreenPoints);
```

I am not sure why is it happening, As far as I know, `Google Map` should get loaded firstly, and then it should wait to pass the location coordinates from the DDMS perspective, but as soon as I launch my application, I get `force closed` with the `NPE`.

Any thoughts why is it happening?

Below is the full code-

```
private MapView mapView;
private ListView listView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

    locationListener = new GPSLocationListener(mapView);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            35000, 
            0, 
            locationListener);


    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(15);
}
```

Location Update class-

```
    private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    MapOverlay mapOverlay;

    public GPSLocationListener(MapView mapView) {
        mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(this,android.R.drawable.star_on);
        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

            mapController.animateTo(point);
            mapController.setZoom(15);

            mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
            mapView.invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

Below is the class which draws a Circle on the Map at the Current Location and **NPE happening in this class only**-

```
    class MapOverlay extends Overlay {
    private GeoPoint pointToDraw;
    int[] imageNames=new int[6];
    private Point mScreenPoints;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Paint mCirclePaint;


    public MapOverlay(GPSLocationListener gpsLocationListener, int currentUser) {
        imageNames[0]=currentUser;
        mCirclePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mCirclePaint.setColor(0x30000000);
        mCirclePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageNames[0]);
        mScreenPoints = new Point();
    }

    public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
        pointToDraw = point;
    }

    public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
        return pointToDraw;
    }

    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

                   // NPE happening here
        mScreenPoints = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, mScreenPoints);

        int totalCircle=4;
        int radius=40;
        int centerimagesize=35;

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalCircle; i ++) { 
            canvas.drawCircle(mScreenPoints.x,mScreenPoints.y, i*radius, mCirclePaint); 
        } 

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, (mScreenPoints.x-(centerimagesize/2)),(mScreenPoints.y-(centerimagesize/2)), null);
        super.draw(canvas,mapView,shadow);

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Update:-**

I found the problem, I guess when I add the overlay to the list, it will always start drawing immediately. It doesn't matter whether or not I get a location. **How can I have a safe and efficient way to add the  to not add the overlay until there is a location to set.?**

Comment: mapView.getProjection() is null? because you aren't waiting for map load to be finished?

Comment: did you debug it to find out where exactly you get the NPE... is mapView null or does mapVie.getProjection() return null, is pointsToDraw or mScreenPoints null?

Comment: @matheszabi, It might be possible, then how can I wait for Map load to be finished? What wrong I am doing?

Comment: or maybe havn't used the setter and the pointToDraw is null? try to break that statement and see where exaxtly is the null and insert an if( myVariable != null){doSomething();} block

Comment: But my question is why it is going directly into that method, as I haven't passed any coordinates from the DDMS perspective. I was waiting for my Map to get loaded firstly and then I will be passing coordinates from the DDMS perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe way:

```
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
    if(pointToDraw == null){ // it isn't found the location yet.
         return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow); // do the default
    }        

   // else:
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

                   // NPE happening here
        mScreenPoints = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, mScreenPoints);

        int totalCircle=4;
        int radius=40;
        int centerimagesize=35;

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalCircle; i ++) { 
            canvas.drawCircle(mScreenPoints.x,mScreenPoints.y, i*radius, mCirclePaint); 
        } 

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, (mScreenPoints.x-(centerimagesize/2)),(mScreenPoints.y-(centerimagesize/2)), null);
        super.draw(canvas,mapView,shadow);

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
```

it will create the map view and starting to load the map.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates
```

you are requesting location, but it will arrive later, who knows when , maybe 50 sec later!

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

            mapController.animateTo(point);
            mapController.setZoom(15);

            mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
            mapView.invalidate();
        }
    }
```

only here are you setting the point, when has arrvied the location

```
mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
```

but the map has been displayed already and draw() has been called.

Comment: I this is your preferred answer, please remove the previous one. Remember that you can always click the `edit` link in the lower left hand corner of your answers to append, amend, or completely rewrite an existing answer.

Comment: I have commented out this line `mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);` but still it throws NPE at the same line `mScreenPoints = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, mScreenPoints);` Why? It looks like my MapOverlay class is getting called automatically in my code.

Comment: I found the problem, I guess when I add the overlay to the list, it will always start drawing immediately. It doesn't matter whether or not I get a location. How can I have a safe and efficient way to add the to not add the overlay until there is a location to set.?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mapView != null){
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    if(projection != null){
          mScreenPoints = projection.toPixels(pointToDraw, mScreenPoints);
    }
    else{
      // log it projection is null
    }
}
else{
   //log it mapView is null
}
```

Now where is the nulllpointer?

Comment: Ok. Found it, I guess. `pointToDraw is Null` But why? Very Strange?

Comment: And also I am strange- Why it is going directly into that method, as I haven't passed any coordinates from the DDMS perspective yet. I was waiting for my Map to get loaded firstly and then I will be passing coordinates from the DDMS perspective. But without loading the Map firstly, it is thinking I have already passed the coordinates but I haven't passed any coordinates and that's why it is NULL i guess. Right?

Comment: for me not, because the only way to not be he null it is the  public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
        pointToDraw = point;
    }  , whit it isn't called before public boolean draw() method

Comment: Then what's wrong? I hope, I am clear what I want from my application. I just need to draw a Circle on my Current Location after every 30 seconds.

Comment: First I would use real device, especially for GPS, Video, Audio, second: I would initialize that pointToDraw  variable to whatever value.

Comment: There is something else wrong for sure. Why this is not loading the Google Map first and wait for me to pass the coordinates from the DDMS? :-/

Comment: Simulator / Emulators are just like sex with condoms :) It isn't real, don't bother to fix they bugg, because you can't, you are in a special environment created to simulate the reality...

Comment: I tested on the real device also, it is taking NULL `pointToDraw`. :(