# XML SAX Parser not working - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

the whole day I tried to figure out how to get my parser working, but for some reason I always get a NullPointerException, here is my code:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    XMLHandler data;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


try {
             Log.i("PARSER", "versuch!");

                /**
                 * Create a new instance of the SAX parser
                 **/

                SAXParserFactory saxPF = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser saxP = saxPF.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xmlR = saxP.getXMLReader();


                URL url = new URL("my xml file"); // URL of the XML

                /** 
                 * Create the Handler to handle each of the XML tags. 
                 **/
                 data = new XMLHandler();
                xmlR.setContentHandler(data);
                xmlR.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                Log.i("PARSER", "ES KLAPPT NICHT!");
            }




        TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview1);
        txt1.setText(data.getTournament().get(0).get(0).getTeam1().toString());

    }
```

**XMLHandler:**

```
public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private Tournament tournament;
    private TournamentDay currentDay;
    private Match currentMatch;
    private StringBuilder builder;

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("team1"))
            currentMatch.setTeam1(builder.toString());
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("team2"))
            currentMatch.setTeam2(builder.toString());
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("resultfinal"))
            currentMatch.setResultfinal(builder.toString());
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("result1"))
            currentMatch.setResult1(builder.toString());
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("result2"))
            currentMatch.setResult2(builder.toString());
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("venue"))
            currentMatch.setVenue(builder.toString());
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("gmt"))
            currentMatch.setGmt(builder.toString());
        else if (qName.equals("match"))
            currentDay.add(currentMatch);
        else if (qName.equals("day"))
            tournament.add(currentDay);
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                             org.xml.sax.Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equals("data")) {
            tournament = new Tournament();
        }
        if (qName.equals("day")) {
            currentDay = new TournamentDay();
        }
        else if (qName.equals("match")) {
            currentMatch = new Match();
        }
        else {
            builder = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] chars, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        builder.append(chars, start, length);
    }

    public Tournament getTournament() {
        return tournament;
    }
}
```

**Tournament:**

```
public class Tournament {

    private List<TournamentDay> days;

    public Tournament() {
        this.days = new ArrayList<TournamentDay>();
    }

    public void add(TournamentDay day) {
        days.add(day);
    }
    public TournamentDay get(int i) {
       return days.get(i); 
    }
}
```

**Match:**

```
public class Match {
    private String team1;
    private String team2;
    private String resultfinal;
    private String result1;
    private String result2;
    private String date;
    private String venue;
    private String gmt;

    public String getTeam1() {
        return team1;
    }

    public void setTeam1(String team1) {
        this.team1 = team1;
    }

    public String getTeam2() {
        return team2;
    }

    public void setTeam2(String team2) {
        this.team2 = team2;
    }

    public String getResultfinal() {
        return resultfinal;
    }

    public void setResultfinal(String resultfinal) {
        this.resultfinal = resultfinal;
    }

    public String getResult1() {
        return result1;
    }

    public void setResult1(String result1) {
        this.result1 = result1;
    }

    public String getResult2() {
        return result2;
    }

    public void setResult2(String result2) {
        this.result2 = result2;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getVenue() {
        return venue;
    }

    public void setVenue(String venue) {
        this.venue = venue;
    }

    public String getGmt() {
        return gmt;
    }

    public void setGmt(String gmt) {
        this.gmt = gmt;
    }

}
```

**And finally my XML file:**

```
<data>
    <day>

        <match>

            <team1>ind</team1>
            <team2>afg</team2>

            <resultfinal></resultfinal>
            <result1></result1>
            <result2></result2>
            <date>19.09</date>
            <venue>1</venue>
            <gmt>14:00</gmt>


        </match>

        <match>

            <team1>eng</team1>
            <team2>afg</team2>

            <resultfinal></resultfinal>
            <result1></result1>
            <result2></result2>

            <date>21.09</date>
            <venue>1</venue>
            <gmt>14:00</gmt>


        </match>
        <match>

            <team1>ind</team1>
            <team2>eng</team2>

            <resultfinal></resultfinal>
            <result1></result1>
            <result2></result2>
            <date>23.09</date>
            <venue>2</venue>
            <gmt>10:00</gmt>


        </match>
    </day>
    <day>
        <match>

            <team1>aust</team1>
            <team2>irl</team2>

            <resultfinal></resultfinal>
            <result1></result1>
            <result2></result2>
            <date>19.08</date>
            <venue>1</venue>
            <gmt>10:00</gmt>


        </match>
        <match>

            <team1>aust</team1>
            <team2>west</team2>

            <resultfinal></resultfinal>
            <result1></result1>
            <result2></result2>
            <date>22.09</date>
            <venue>1</venue>
            <gmt>14:00</gmt>


        </match>
        <match>

            <team1>west</team1>
            <team2>irl</team2>

            <resultfinal></resultfinal>
            <result1></result1>
            <result2></result2>

            <date>24.09</date>
            <venue>1</venue>
            <gmt>14:00</gmt>


        </match>

    </day>

</data>
```

**Here is the logcat:**

```
09-17 15:26:49.299: I/System.out(3392): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 15:26:49.299: I/PARSER(3392): ES KLAPPT NICHT!
09-17 15:26:49.299: D/AndroidRuntime(3392): Shutting down VM
09-17 15:26:49.299: W/dalvikvm(3392): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb40a64f0)
09-17 15:26:49.299: I/Process(3392): Sending signal. PID: 3392 SIG: 9
09-17 15:26:49.299: D/AndroidRuntime(3392): procName from cmdline: com.example.xmldownloader
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.xmldownloader
09-17 15:26:49.299: D/AndroidRuntime(3392): file written successfully with content: com.example.xmldownloader StringBuffer : ;com.example.xmldownloader
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xmldownloader/com.example.xmldownloader.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1698)
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1726)
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:949)
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3770)
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     at com.example.xmldownloader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1662)
09-17 15:26:49.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3392):     ... 11 more
```

Can somebody help me with this? Or point out, what I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: what code it is at: MainActivity.java:58 ? - there is the NullPointerException!

Comment: that is this: txt1.setText(data.getTournament().get(0).get(0).getTeam1().toString());
that is where I want to test the data stored, but yes, as you already mentioned I get that error. But I don't know why, or what I did wrong

Comment: If this is line 58, then this is your problem: `txt1.setText(data.getTournament().get(0).get(0).getTeam1().toString());`.  It sure looks like a problem to me :)  SUGGESTION: break your (many!) "getXX()" into separate statements, and fix the first one that returns "null" ;)  Then see if any *subsequent* "getters" return null, and fix them, too.

Comment: I broke them into seperate statements, but now I realiesd that they did not even get called. The problem is in the XML Handler, but I don't know what's wrong with it

Comment: Hi - The stack trace clearly says "line 58", you said "line 58 === setText (data.getSomething().getSomethingElse().getAnotherThing()...)", which certainly *looks* suspicious!  SUGGESTION: put a bunch of "printfs" in your startElement(), endElement(), print out the inputs, and see how far you get.  IMHO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
txt1.setText(data.getTournament().get(0).get(0).getTeam1().toString());
```

it is not a code, where you would like to look at it!
Please split it into one statement per line, and log it!

Exactly the same it was the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452663/force-closed-with-null-pointer-exception-in-android/12452802#12452802) too.

Comment: I broke them into seperate statements, but now I realiesd that they did not even get called. The problem is in the XML Handler, but I don't know what's wrong with it

Comment: for that maybe you would like to break the xmlR.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream())); statement too in separate declaration and check the inputstream and so on

Comment: ah ok I now know where the problem was. Thanks!

Comment: I did me too the same programming errors, like 12 years ago, now I am thinking twice if I really need 2 statements on the same line. NullPointerException it a clear sign of beginner ( wrong ) code or bugg in frameworks, os.

Comment: Yes, I will now remember if I really need so many statements in on line. Thanks again :)